# How to prevent repeating values in Telerik RadGridView column

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding, telerik, radgridview

I have a radgridview with three columns: **Company, Name, Status**.

I want to try to prevent repeating instances of the company name when sorted by that column to avoid it showing the same company name over and over and over. Each row is bound to a single viewmodel where it gets its cell data from.

Is there anything I could use to accomplish this, so that a cell can check the cell in the same column in the row above it and if it's the same value, hide its own value so as to not repeat the same company name?

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion would be to listen out for one of the `Sorting` or `Sorted` events and then you should be able to hide the data in some way. If nothing else I'd assume that you could use [CellStyleSelector](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/gridview-cell-style-selector.html) change the style of cells to have white text on a white background or something similar.

However, it might be worth asking Telerik themselves since I think they offer free help with these kinds of questions and they might have a better answer.